# Place a JSPDF-generated pdf into an iframe

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, jspdf, pdf.js

I have the following piece of code that generates a pdf using the https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF library:

```js
var generatePdfFromHtml = function(pdf, html, callback) {
  console.log("Generating Pdf");
  pdf.html(html, {
    'callback': function(pdf) {
      if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
        console.log("Offering Pdf as callback");
        callback(pdf);
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   * @var {jsPDF} pdf
   */
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

  $("#myform").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $("#inputData").val();
    /* Dummy Html to emulate the situation I am */
    val = "<b>" + val + "</b>";
    generatePdfFromHtml(pdf, val, function(returnedPDF) {
      var blob = pdfFromCallback.output('blob');
      console.log(blob)
      /* Write Pdf into #display Iframe */
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input id="inputData" name="metallica" placeholder="Enter a metallica song"><button type="submit">Enter Sandman</button>
</form>

<iframe id="display"></iframe>
```

What I want is to place the generated blob pdf into the iframe having id `#display` do you know how to do that?

I also found that Mozilla has made the `pdf.js` allowing us to renbder pdf when not supported thus in case that pdf rendering not supported how I can use pdf.js to render it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code I edited in order to render the pdf into an `iframe`:

```js
var generatePdfFromHtml = function(pdf, html, callback) {
  console.log("Generating Pdf");
  pdf.html(html, {
    'callback': function(pdf) {
      if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
        console.log("Offering Pdf as callback");
        callback(pdf);
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   * @var {jsPDF} pdf
   */
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

  $("#myform").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $("#inputData").val();
    /* Dummy Html to emulate the situation I am */
    val = "<b>" + val + "</b>";
    generatePdfFromHtml(pdf, val, function(returnedPDF) {
      console.log("Generated Pdf");
      var blob = pdfFromCallback.output('blob');
      /* Write Pdf into #display Iframe */
      var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var iframeElementContainer = document.getElementById('display');
      iframeElementContainer.src=blob_url;
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input id="inputData" name="metallica" placeholder="Enter a metallica song"><button type="submit">Enter Sandman</button>
</form>

<iframe id="display" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;"></iframe>
```

As you can see the following piece of code does the job:

```
 var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 var iframeElementContainer = document.getElementById('display');
 iframeElementContainer.src=blob_url;
```

In other words we actually generate a url and we set it as the iframe's src. The dirty job of generating the url is the `URL.createObjectURL` function.